# How do I place a static wallpaper in my Tumblr theme?

Tags: theme

How do I place a static wallpaper in this HTML theme?

http://static.tumblr.com/taepiis/5SFln832d/theme.txt

Answer (score 1):

Change this block:

```
body {
    background: #fafafa url('http://static.tumblr.com/l3zugnz/7KJkvwe70/bg.png') fixed repeat-x 0 0;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

to read:

```
body {
    background: #fafafa url('http://path.com/to/your/image.jpg') fixed no-repeat 0 0;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Replace `http://path.com/to/your/image.jpg` with the actual path to your new background image. You could upload the new background image on tumblr's [static file upload page](http://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file) and use the URL it gives you.